# Why change time of historical .hprof file has been changed

Tags: java, hprof

As I mentioned in title, I am wondering about the changing reason that changing time of my historical `.hprof` files has been changed.

The scenario of my problem is:

I have a `.hprof` file generated several month ago because of memory leaking occurred, so that I have fixed issue and restart the relevant java process. After that, this dumped file is abandoned where it was generated.

Meanwhile, I have a running monitor which will be triggered once change time is updated (using `find -cmin`).

As a result, I received an alert that change time of my archived `.hprof` file is updated.

No one changed the permission of files manually, so I thought i there any situation that java will do it by itself?

Please tell me about something of this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that new file was generated and old one was replaced by it? Java do not do anything with `.hprof` files by itself.

Comment: The `.hprof` file was generated at May 24th, The modify time is still the time when it was generated, but only the change time was updated. So in my view, the file should not be covered by a new one. By the way, the pid in the file name is also not available any more.

Comment: pid is not available because your server was restarted.

Comment: So do you mean that the file will still be appended or even covered after I have restart the server? After all, my issue is the change time is updated, which in my opinion is not possible to happen.

Comment: No. Java do not append this files.